# regular expression to match inside parentheses

Tags: regex, perl

I want to do the following match and capture the group

```
(inside),(inside),...,(inside)
```

or

```
(inside)
```

That is, either the same `inside` appears multiple times inside parentheses and separated by a comma, or it only appear once inside parentheses.

The capture group is the stuff `inside`. Could anybody help me?

Thanks.

**change**

Sorry that I did not make it clear. The stuff `inside` may contain parentheses, but not comma. That is the way it is distinguished.

Comment: Could you please show an example ("real") string, with the desired output (match) - this is really not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a back-reference to test that the same string is repeated.

```
/^\(([^,]*)\)(?:,\(\1\))*$/
```

[DEMO](http://regexr.com?37kpl)

Comment: hi, sorry that I missed one important condition. Could you please take another look?